# Display lightning-icon in lightning-input and add onclick action

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, lightninginput, lightning-inputfield

I'm trying to add icon inside input and that's fine, but when i try to add some action like onclick it doesn't work.
On front when i try to click on the icon i can not do this, cuz input hover it ;/

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" style="width: -webkit-fill-available;">
                <div class="icon-container" onclick={handleShowHidePassword}>
                    <lightning-icon  size="small" class="front slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" icon-name={iconName}></lightning-icon>
                </div>
                <lightning-input class="login-input slds-m-bottom_medium" type={inputType} label={label.labelPassword} value={password} required data-name="password" onchange={handleInputChange} ></lightning-input>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i find out the solution

```
style="pointer-events: painted;"
```

I added this style to lightning-icon and it's start recognize events